# the values not remain in the Text Form Field when I click continue, when I return to the page the value is empty Note that I used Page View

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to make Sign Up pages so I used Page View like this page view controller.nextPage(....,...) page view controller.prev page(....,...) Boom Value in the Text Form Field is gone. And this thing happens on all pages when I move to a new page in the page view and return to the page. The information that the user filled in is gone from the fields and has become empty! why?

```
   Form(
      key: EmailKeys.formKey,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          const Text(
            "Create an account, It's free",
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.grey),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 40,
          ),
          TextFormField(
            onFieldSubmitted: (val) {
              EmailKeys.formKey.currentState!.setState(() {
                email = val.trim();
              });
              EmailKeys.formKey.currentState!.save();
            },
            textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
            inputFormatters: [LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(100)],
            obscureText: false,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: "Email Address",
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
              ),
              labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[400]),
              floatingLabelStyle:
                  const TextStyle(color: Colors.blueGrey, fontSize: 18),
            ),
            validator: (value) {
              if (value!.isEmpty) {
                return 'Email address is required';
              } else if (!value.contains("@")) {
                return "Email address should contain ' @ ' symbol";
              }
            },
            onChanged: (value) {
              email = value.trimLeft();
            },
            onSaved: (val) {
              setState(() {
                email = val!;
              });
              print(email);
            },
            controller: _emailCtrl,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
```

Comment: you need to store data locally otherwise when back from another page data will be removed. And you can also try with state-management like bloc, globalState, and etc.

Answer (score 0):

try to pass `email` to TextFormField as value